# Smart pointer Class variable Destructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, alignment, smart-pointers

I have classX that contains a shared pointer

`std::shared_ptr<T> sharedPTR;`

I want the pointer stored in the shared pointer to be aligned, so in every constructor I have I initialize the sharedPTR like this

```
this->sharedPTR.reset((T*) _mm_malloc(this->size, 64))
```

But this causes mismatched frees/deletes simce the default destructor calles `delete ptr` where ptr is the pointer stored in the smart pointer

***Note*** I am aware that we can use this

```
this->sharedPTR = std::shared_ptr<T>((T *) _mm_malloc(this->mSize, 64), 
[](T* ptr){ _mm_free(ptr);});
```

but I have so many constructors I'll have to keep repeating this every time and it does not look good.

Comment: Call a common utility function from each of your constructors?

Comment: Yep, create a `make_shared_aligned<T>` utility function to hide away this detail